# How to get a title to scroll above an iOS text view

Tags: ios, textview

I want to have a text title scroll above a text view, but can't find information on how to do it.  I've been looking for days, but can't even figure out how to look for the info.  I want the function to work like the Apple Notes app where the date text is positioned above the text entry location and scrolls off the screen with the text but is not editable.

I've tried placing labels above UITextView, but the label does not scroll with the textView.  I have a sample Xcode project I'm work with, but not sure if it can be uploaded for others to see what I'm doing. I almost had success with the project, but the labels only scroll with the text in the landscape view, not the portrait view for some reason.

I've read Apple developer docs on TextViews and several other sources without finding any discussion on how to do this or examples to follow.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there must be a better way to do this, but this is the only approach I've found to work after more than a week of trying to find a solution.  If I can figure out how to upload the entire Xcode example project I will do that.

This is the explanation of the approach I found to work under iOS 6.1 and Xcode 4.5. I have only tired this on the iPhone 6.1 simulator.

After creating a full screen text view and placing a label at the top of the text view,
To get the label to scroll off screen with the editable text view you need to:

1. turn off autolayout in interface builder (uncheck Use Autolayout). (there appears to be a problem with autoLayout and scrollViews in iOS 6.x)
2. turn off the text view scrolling in interface builder (uncheck Scrolling Enabled)
3. set the text view content insets height (Top) to the label height
4. embed the text view and label in a scroll view.
5. set properties for the scroll view and text view to be able to access their properties
6. in viewDidAppear:animated:
   a. set the scroll view content size height to 20 plus the greater of the screen view height or the text view content height plus the label height
   b. set the text view delegate to self

   ```
   -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
       [super viewDidAppear:animated];

       float screenHeight = self.view.bounds.size.height;

       // set the scroll view content height to 20 plus the greater of the view height or the text view content size height plus the label height

       screenHeight = MAX(screenHeight, self.textView.contentSize.height + 20);
       self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, 20 + screenHeight);

       // set the text view delegate
       self.textView.delegate = self;
   }
   ```
7. set the text view height dynamically in textView delegate method textViewDidChange:
   a. if the text view content height is greater than the view bounds height less the label height:
       1. set the text view frame to the view bounds width and the text view content height plus the lable height
       2. set the scroll view content height to the view bounds width and the text view bounds height plus the label height

   ```
   // dynamically set the text view content size height
   -(void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {

       if (self.textView.contentSize.height > self.view.bounds.size.height - 20) {

           self.textView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.textView.contentSize.height + 20);

           self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.textView.bounds.size.height + 20);
       }

   }
   ```

set the struts and springs in interface builder
1. set the scroll view and text view struts for left, right and bottom
2. set the scroll view and text view springs for width and height
3. set the label struts for left, right and top
4. set the label spring for width

The same settings need to be made every time the view changes orientations.

There might be a way to do this by setting constraints in code under autolayout, but I barely understand constraints, much less setting them successfully in code.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I can't figure out how to upload an Xcode project here so I've loaded the project on GitHub.com at the following link. https://github.com/ShepherdAtFoL/iOS-Examples

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called UIScrollView. Take a look at the Apple documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html).

A good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content) on UIScrollView can be found on the Ray Wenderlich site.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.I've looked at UIscrollView and that is where I had limited success by placing the label and textView inside a scrollView, however the label only scrolled in the landscape view not the portrait view.  I'll relook at the docs to see if there needs to be a different setting for the different orientations, but I did not see anything mentioned about using different setups for different orientations.

Comment: Take a look at the tutorial link. With UIScrollView you can scroll (move) in all directions. The class does have its quirks however so you have to be a little patient while learning it. You can also search Stackoverflow for 'UIScrollView example' and get a lot of information that way too.

Comment: The tutorial was great.  I hope to find what I'm looking to do by implementing some of the information from it.  So far not working, but I will keep trying until it does and post the solution here when I find it.  thanks

Comment: No success in getting the action I'm looking for.  Using a textView and a label (the title) embedded in a scroll view, works fine as long as there is not enough text in the text view to cause the text view to scroll.  Once the text view starts to scroll, then the label no longer scrolls (the scroll view no longer scrolls) until the text view reaches the end of its scroll, then the scroll view will scroll the label off the screen.  The desired action is what is seen in Apple's notes app where the date at the top of the note scrolls off screen with the note contents.